# jQuery, jQuery UI, and Dual Licensed Plugins (Dual Licensing)

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, licensing

OK I have read many posts regarding Dual Licensing using MIT and GPL licenses.  But Im curious still, as the wording seems to be inclusive.  Many of the Dual Licenses state that the software is licensed using "MIT AND GPL".  The "AND" is what confuses me.

It seems to me that the word "AND" in the terms, means you will be licensing the product using both licenses.   Most of the posts, here on stackoverflow, state that you can license the software using one "OR" the other.

[JQuery](http://jquery.org/license) specifically states "OR", whereas [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/about) specifically States "AND".
Another Instance of the "AND" would be [JQGrid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=78).

Im not a lawyer but, it seems to me that a legal interpretation of this would state that use of the software would mean that your using the software under both licenses.  Has anyone who has contacted a lawyer gotten clarification or a definitive answer as to what is true?  Can you use Dual licensed software products that state "AND" in the terms of agreement under either license?

**EDITED:**
    Guys here is specifically what Im talking about on jquery.org/license you see the following stated:

> You may use any jQuery project under
>   the terms of either the MIT License or
>   the GNU General Public License (GPL)
>   Version 2

but in the header of Jquery's and Jquery UI library you see this:

```
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
```

The site says

> MIT or GPL

but the license statement in the software says

> MIT and GPL.

**UPDATE May 7, 2010**
There is clearly something to this question as JQuery has changed the wording of thier licence agreement in thier latest release to state MIT **OR** GPL.

Release 1.3.2 license says:

```
/*
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.3.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright (c) 2009 John Resig
 * Dual licensed under the MIT and GPL licenses.
 * http://docs.jquery.com/License
 *
 * Date: 2009-02-19 17:34:21 -0500 (Thu, 19 Feb 2009)
 * Revision: 6246
 */
```

But now Release 1.4.2 license says:

```
/*!
 * jQuery JavaScript Library v1.4.2
 * http://jquery.com/
 *
 * Copyright 2010, John Resig
 * Dual licensed under the MIT or GPL Version 2 licenses.
 * http://jquery.org/license
*/
```

Comment: http://jquery.org/license seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: Craig, I know it seems clear but JQuery UI states the licensing usage differently on another page: example "The jQuery UI library is currently available for use in all personal or commercial projects under both MIT and GPL licenses. " Note the "AND" between the licensing usage. JQuery UI is not the only dual licence I see like this. Many of the plugins for Jquery also state thier terms of use in this way. My question is about Interpretation. If I said "make this and that", its different than saying "make this or that". So has anyone actually spoken with an attorney regarding this?

Comment: I'm searching exactly this subject and I read on http://jquery.org/license that "You are free to use a jQuery project in commercial projects as long as the copyright header is left intact." And I'm pretty happy with this!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

John Resig owns the copyrights to the code and  he can license it to anybody he wants and under any terms he wants within the constraints of copyright law.

He has chosen to license the code under GPLv2, perhaps because he wants to encourage the producers of other GPL licenced products to use this software.

He has also chosen to license the code under the MIT license, perhaps because he wants to encourage producers of open-source and proprietary code to use this software.

If you read over the licenses, a piece of software cannot be GPL and MIT at the same time. GPL requires that distributors of derivative works distribute the entire source code of the entire derived work. MIT allows distributors of derivative works to withhold the source code.  This is logically impossible. I suspect that when he dual-licensed the software, he meant that the two licenses were GPL and MIT. More specifically he did not say that the license (singular) is GPL and MIT.

Remember that you are the owner of the copyrights of any derivative works (e.g. applications that use/modify the open source software plus your own software). If derived  your software from anything that is licensed under the GPL, you only had that right to make the derivative work if you agreed to license your derivative work under the GPL to anybody to whom you distribute the derivative work).

If you derived your application from MIT-licensed software then you are the copyright owner and you can license your application under any terms you want, including the exchange of money for a right to use the application. Apple Computer does that with their FreeBSD operating system base (licensed under a MIT-like license), and their proprietary Mac OS-X code on top.

Therefore, you should pick the license that suits your project and go with it. Usually it is more prudent to use the MIT license if you are a business that sells software but would like to keep the source code written by you secret. You will do better to pick GPL if you would like to ensure that the code base of your application remains liberated for anybody to study, use, and modify.

Having said that, you can still mix GPL code with MIT code without violating the terms of either license. The Linux folks do it all of the time with the kernel (GPL) and linked device drivers (GPL, MIT and some others). However, if you distribute the application, you must distribute the code base of the entire derived work including the GPL licensed software and the MIT licensed software, and you must license it to your customers under the GPL.

Check out my page at [Squidoo](http://www.squidoo.com/software_ip_management) for more insight.

Comment: Jay thanks for your comments but I still have a question.  You stated "I suspect that when he dual-licensed the software, he meant that the two licenses were GPL and MIT. More specifically he did not say that the license (singular) is GPL and MIT.",  I understand that you obviously have been in contact with an attorney (BF Lippett, since you refer her at your site. But my question still stands as your statement makes an assumption, probably a true assumption, but still an assumption.

Comment: John - The "about" page for jqueryui at http://jqueryui.com/about points to this page at http://jquery.org/license for licensing.  This page tells you that you can pick either MIT or GPLv2 and use their code.

Comment: Your example for JQueryUI describes the confusion im seeing.  JQuery UI's license header at the top of the JS library states "AND" but the web site points to a reference that states "OR".  How would a lawyer or court interpret this?  I know your not a lawyer or "the court" but my curiousity still stands. I do appreciate the input.

Comment: Good point. I send an email to John Resig to see if he could weigh in on this ... we'll see.

Comment: Jay, I hav also contacted John Resig to get clarification.  Thanks for your input.

Comment: Then I wonder why the dual licensing is necessary? If jQuery is single-licensed as MIT. Then my derived work can choose to use whatever license I want (including GPL). Isn't it then licensing as MIT already covers GPL's usage scenario and thus the GPL is redundant?

Comment: Just to add a little info: jQuery project has adopted to a single license scheme and dropped off GNU GPL. details and reference: http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/10/jquery-licensing-changes/

Answer (score 8):

I've updated the copyright for all jQuery UI source files to match the wording from jQuery core. http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/commit/536ae6189bf0f0de1113bf9ec7054da693544e1f

Comment: Thanks for that.  It is helpful.  Curious if you know the details about Sizzle.js which is incorporated into Jquery.  Sizzle.js has a triple license with the Clause "AND".  Do you have any influence in getting this changed to "OR"

Answer (score 5):

GPL explicitly forbids adding additional restrictions, so the only valid form of dual-licensing is to allow users to use it according to the GPL licence OR use it according to the MIT license (which is what dual-licensing means, anyway).

Comment: You make a good point but I must ask. Since the MIT license is so much less restrictive stating the following "MIT and GPL" would not add restricitons to the GPL license.  Or are you saying that there are parts of the MIT license that are in conflict (would mean additional restrictions for the GPL license)?

Comment: I haven't thought of that. There is probably no conflict as GPL allows yout to attach copyright notices to the code and require reusers to keep them, and that is the only thing required by MIT. Still, the term "dual licensing" itself is generally understood as allowing a choice (check [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_licensing) for example), no matter the wording, so a court would probably interpret it so. I am no lawyer tho.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery is no longer dual licensed. jQuery projects are now only distributed under the MIT license, which is GPL compatible. The majority copyright is now held by jQuery Foundation as all team members have signed a Copyright Assignment Agreement. Non-team members are now required to sign a [Contributor License Agreement](http://jquery.github.com/cla.html), but they still retain copyright of their contributions, just as they did before. We have updated all projects to include an AUTHORS.txt file listing all contributors. You can read more about this in [a recent blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/09/10/jquery-licensing-changes/).

Answer (score 3):

I'm also not a layer, but I think the AND/OR just depends on point of view. The code is licensed under both licenses (AND), while you can use it under term of either license (OR).

Comment: Thanks for your input and time, but "point of view" and interpretation is what this question is about. I know your not a lawyer, but I posted here because I was assuming someone has consulted an attorney regarding Dual Licensed open source projects.

Answer (score -1):

IANAL and you shouldn't get legal advice from a website.  But in my opinion there are only two possible reasons to care about licensing:

1. You want to use the code.  You need the copyright holder's permission, and thus you must use it under whatever license the copyright holder(s) gives you.  In this case you get to choose because it is dual-licensed.  It is a logical contradiction to license the software simultaneously under both licenses at the same time because the GPL adds requirements that the MIT license does not.  Therefore you as the user can choose one OR the other.  Note: if you are distributing the code you can presumably carry-forward the dual-licensing too if your own project is dual-licensed accordingly.  But if you want to operate under the terms of just one license you can.
2. You want to contribute to the code.  In that case you need to know that your code will also be dual-licensed.  For example, it is generally impossible to contribute to the Linux kernel any code that isn't GPLv2.  And if you ONLY want to contribute GPL code (because you are a strong believer in copyleft) then you must be aware that jQuery is GPL *AND* MIT, which means your code must be similarly GPL and MIT.

Comment: Point 2 is wrong. If you want to distribute a derivative work of MIT-licensed code you can choose ANY license you want. You are not bound to use GPL, MIT or anything else. (And I didn't even downvote this).

Comment: @Jay Godse: Maybe you misunderstood my point 2. If I want to contribute code to a project which is dual-licensed, I need to be aware of that fact and can't contribute GPL-only code to that project.

Comment: Shiny and New - Good point. Your point is valid if you are ceding your copyrights to the owner of the copyrights of the original work (which could be a group of people which includes you). I was going with the assumption that you were doing a fork-and-run.

Comment: @Jay Godse: I'm not sure what you mean by ceding copyright. I am refering to the case where a project (such as Jquery) is dual licensed, and I want to give them some code, but am not granting them copyright. They get to use my code by virtue of the license I grant them. But since they distribute THEIR (combined) work under TWO licenses, they will only accept my code if it is under BOTH licenses.

Comment: Shiny and New - Not quite. If you give them a patch of code, and your name is not on the list of copyright owners of the patch you gave them then you have tacitly transferred your copyrights of the patch to them. If you license your patch to them under GPL then they can only distribute the combined work under GPL (and they'll probably refuse your patch).  If you license it to them under MIT, then they can dual license the combined work under GPL or MIT.

Comment: @Jay Godse: I don't think copyright transfer happens so easily. Without a formal contract, I'm pretty sure copyright remains with the author. That's why so many projects require explicit copyright assignment. As for the contributor who single-licenses his contribution under MIT license, sure, his code can obviously be included in the GPL work. But the GPL-only contributor, as you said, would be rejected, and any other contributor who sees "GPL" and assumes it's ONLY GPL may be upset to find that it's GPL + MIT.